# How to access dot directory

Tags: directory, dot-files

I’ve been googling on how to access dot directory in unix like system, but everybody is just talking about dot directories for this and that reason. I haven’t found anything on how to get to directory /mnt/fn/.system? See what is inside.

for instance

```
cd mnt

cd fn
```

and then what?

Comment: The same way you cd anywhere... by specifying its name!

Comment: When I checked `# zpool status` on my FreeNAS, it returned that
    `errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:
     /mnt/fn/.system:<0x9a>`

When I wanted to see what is in .system directory I’ve got 
   ` .system: No such file or directory.`

Then I went googling and asking here.

Now the error disappeared in `# zpool status` report. Also the .system directory disappeared - from `ls -a` command.

----

You all still answered what I wanted to know - how to access a dot directory.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot meaning "this directory" dot dot meaning prev directory. 
When the file or directory start with dot meaning "hide"
"Hide" for ls or other commands, not for FS. So if you run ls /home/foo you don't see files or directory starting with dot.
If you run "rm -r /home/foo/*" all files will be delete. Not the files or directories starting with dot.
Now, in case of directory, this need execute permission, at least for owner. Doesn't matter if start with dot or not. X permission meaning "descend" o "execute".
Try remove x

Comment: This is hard to follow, can you try and clean it up? LMK if you need assistance.

Answer (score 4):

.. and then `cd .system`. The presence of a dot at the start of really doesn't mean much of anything except to make it "hidden" - i.e. it won't appear in a default `ls` listing unless you specify `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
cd .system
```

Longer answer:
You do not see the .system directory when you run ls because the dot in front makes it "hidden". To see it, run ls with the -a flag:

```
$ ls -a /mnt/fn
.
..
.system
```

You can always just do:

```
$ cd /mnt/fn/.system
```